# linker says _IsolationAwareLoadLibrary is undefined - any ideas?

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio, linker

I added some boost stuff* to my code and the linking phase failed with:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _IsolationAwareLoadLibraryA@4 referenced in function "void * __cdecl boost::interprocess::winapi::load_library(char const *)" (?load_library@winapi@interprocess@boost@@YAPAXPBD@Z)

Can anyone help me figure this out? kernel32.lib is added in linker settings. I searched for _IsolationAwareLoadLibraryA and it doesn't seem to be present in Windows SDK 6.0A, which I'm using. The project is CLR if that matters.

*the boost stuff are two shared memory headers:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
```

Comment: What boost stuff did you add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the project I used had a "ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED=1" added to preprocessor definitions. Removing it fixed the linker error. Not sure whether this won't cause any other problems though. The disturbing fact is that I'm wasting lots of time just resolving various issues related to building my project with third-party C/C++ libraries.

Answer (score 1):

This functions are part of SDK 7.0A, and they should be inline (so there's no need to specify an .lib file). Try downloading and using a newer SDK, and make sure that ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED gets #defined, because this is what triggers the inclusion of those functions. I guess boost should define it by itself though.